# Get the highest attribute value from a set of DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of DOM elements with data attributes. How can I get the maximum value?

```
<li data-for-something="1"></li>
<li data-for-something="1"></li>
<li data-for-something="2"></li>
<li data-for-something="3"></li>
<li data-for-something="4"></li>
```

I can use `$('[data-some-value]')` to get all the `li` with this attribute, and then loop through them. But I'm not sure what js or jquery methods are available to make this easier.

The best I've got is doing this:

```
function getMaxAttributeValue(attribute_name) {
  var max_value = 0;
  $('[' + attribute_name + ']').map(function(){
    var this_value = this.attr(attribute_name);
    if (this_value > max_value) {
      max_value = this_value;
    }
  });
  return max_value;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like this way:

```
function getMaxAttributeValue(attribute_name) {
  return Math.max.apply( Math, $('[' + attribute_name + ']').map(function(){
    return Number($(this).attr(attribute_name)) || -Infinity;
  }))
}

console.log(getMaxAttributeValue("data-for-something"))  // outputs 4
```

Comment: @DonnyP in case you have non-numeric attribute, will still work even if you have a li with `data-for-something="a"`

Answer (score 0):

I think @juvian's answer is probably the best, however I fiddled around with this before I saw his answer, so I thought I'm going to share the way I wanted to do it. It's not a function, but works perfectly with your html structure. I made use of the `dataset` property.

```
var array = new Array;

$('li').each( function() { 
    array.push(parseInt($(this)[0].dataset.forSomething));
});

console.log(Math.max.apply(Math, array));
```

I added this to this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vVkr6/